# How to manually show an HTML validation message from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, constraint-validation-api

I want to know if there is any way to programmatically show a HTML validation error, using a JavaScript function.

This is useful for scenarios where email duplication has to be checked. For example, a person enters an email, presses the Submit button, and then has to be notified that this email is already registered or something.

I know there are other ways of showing such an error, but I wanted to display it in the same way as how the validation error messages are shown (e.g. invalid email, empty field, etc.).

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/tjXG3/

**HTML Form:**

```
<form>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here..." required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    
<button id="triggerMsg" onclick="triggerCustomMsg()">Trigger Custom Message</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function triggerCustomMsg()
{
    document.getElementById("email").setCustomValidity("This email is already used");
    
}
```

The above code sets the custom message, but its not automatically shown. It's only shown when the person presses the submit button or something.

Comment: You will have to trigger submission of the form to get the message to appear

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/tjXG3/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/tjXG3/2/) using jquery

Answer (score 39):

You can now use the HTMLFormElement.reportValidity() method, at the moment it's implemented in most browsers except Internet Explorer (see [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity#Browser_compatibility) at MDN). It reports validity errors without triggering the submit event and they are shown in the same way.

Comment: reportValidity() method is good but it gives its own error message, how to use reportValidity with a custom error message?

Comment: @PratikKumar I belive you can use [`HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity)

Answer (score 28):

```
var applicationForm = document.getElementById("applicationForm");    
if (applicationForm.checkValidity()) {
  applicationForm.submit();
} else {
  applicationForm.reportValidity();
}
```

reportValidity() method will trigger HTML5 validation message.

Answer (score 5):

This question was asked over a year ago, but it's a good question that I recently encountered as well...

My solution was to use JavaScript to create an attribute (I went with "data-invalid") on the `<label>` of each `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` containing the [validationMessage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/constraints.html#dom-cva-validationmessage).

Then some CSS...

```
label:after {
    content: attr(data-invalid);
   ...
}
```

... displays the error message.

**Limitations**

This only works provided each element has a label. It will not work if you put the attribute on the element itself, because `<input>` elements cannot have `:after` pseudo elements.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/u4ca6kvm/2/

Answer (score 3):

As mentoned by @Diego you can use form.reportValidity();
To support IE and Safari include this polyfill, it just works:

```
if (!HTMLFormElement.prototype.reportValidity) {
    HTMLFormElement.prototype.reportValidity = function() {
      if (this.checkValidity()) return true;
      var btn = document.createElement('button');
      this.appendChild(btn);
      btn.click();
      this.removeChild(btn);
      return false;
    }
}
```